# UwAmp server doesn't detect changes that've made in files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web, uwamp

everyone!

- I'm using UwAmp 3.1.0 for my php development but I had some troubles
  with it.

---

- It worked perfectly at the beginning and the server still works
  perfectly now but **whenever I made a change to a .js file or .php

  file it doesn't reflect that change when I update the page in the

  browser**.

---

I went to the chrome dev tools and opened the source section to see      if the file is exactly what I wanted but it shows the original       version which I've amended a while ago. The links to all files are       correct and they are in a subdirectory in **www folder**.

It's so frustrating as I can't see the changes in action. I checked
   the syntax and everything is ok but it doesn't want to stop an
   animation in jquery after I it was fully shown to the user.

---

**Can you help me with this situation as I have no idea what's causing the problem here?**

It should update the file instantly when I click refresh in the
   browser but it doesn't and keeps loading the version of the files
   that I started to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uwamp is **AMP stack** (Apache, MySql and PHP) and "out-of-the-box" it doesn't have anything with caching of files.

Apache is normally reading/getting files from Uwmap www folder "**as is**" so basically if your last change is saved into file in www folder (please check directly with tools like notepad)  Apache *will read it instantly*.

This is related to your Browser **Cache** (Empty yours Browser/Chrome cache manually  or install Chrome extension like [Clear Cache Extension]:https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn?hl=en) and try to clear cache but completely ("from begining of time" like Chrome said).

Also a workaround is to click that Empty Cache icon every save before refreshing the page beacuse it will clear it almost instantly (depending on how long time ago have you cleared your cache)

Also try to set **OPCache** in Php.ini (settings file) in Uwmap to Disabled (locate opcache settings in php.ini and put 0 to disable - you can access it from Uwamp GUI also).

Comment: If you want to refresh the page and empty the cache, just press ctrl + F5